# SetState using the foreach loop does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state using the following code:

```
handleCheckBox = () => {
    this.setState(({isCheckd}) => ({isCheckd: !isCheckd, isEnable: !isCheckd}), () => 
      this.props.untracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd })),
      this.props.tracked.forEach((item) => this.setState({ [item.resumeId]: this.state.isCheckd }))
    );
  }
```

When I try to update using the `forEach` function. In the first loop the state gets updated as you see the conditons are the same. but in this first one gets change but second for each does not get change. If I change the order in which they are written then the whichever is first it's state gets changed but not the second one.

```
handleTableCheckboxChange = (e, type) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
    }, () => {
      const checkedItems = this.props[type].filter((item) => this.state[item.resumeId])
      this.setState({
        isCheckd: checkedItems.length === this.props[type].length ? true : false,
        isEnable: checkedItems.length > 1 ? true : false
      });
    });
  }
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Although you can call setState in a loop, IMHO is better to collect in the loop all the changes and apply a sigle setState after the loop.

Comment: Doing multile setState() in one loop is not recommended, since it will re-render the site every time setState is called. It is better do a forEach to collect all the data you need and call one setState to apply the changes.

Comment: Why are you doing `setState` in the completion handler of a previous `setState`? And why have `tracked` and `untracked` when you're doing the same thing with both?

Comment: Actually both are the diff tables.so both are having the diff data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comments on your previous question, you're breaking one of the [fundamental rules of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous): If you're setting state *based on existing state*, you **must** use the callback version of `setState`, not the version you pass an object into.

Looking at that code, doing so would look something like this:

```
handleCheckBox = () => {
  this.setState(
    ({isCheckd}) => ({isCheckd: !isCheckd, isEnable: !isCheckd}),
    () => this.setState(({isCheckd}) => {
      const newState = {};
      for (const item of [...this.props.untracked, ...this.props.tracked]) {
        newState[item.resumeId] = isCheckd;
      }
      return newState;
    })
  );
}
```

**But**, a couple of odd things jump out:

1. It's not clear why you're calling `setState` again in the completion handler of the outer `setState`.
2. It's not clear why you have `tracked` and `untracked` when you're doing the same thing with them.

If you can do it in *one* state update, that would probably be better:

```
handleCheckBox = () => {
  this.setState(({isCheckd}) => {
    const newState = {
      isCheckd: !isCheckd,
      isEnable: !isCheckd
    };
    for (const item of [...this.props.untracked, ...this.props.tracked]) {
      newState[item.resumeId] = isCheckd;
    }
    return newState;
  });
}
```

---

Re your updated question, `handleTableCheckboxChange` has the same problem (setting state based on existing state passing an object into `setState`) and thus the same solution (use the callback version) applies:

```
handleTableCheckboxChange = ({target: {name, checked}}, type) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const newState = {[name]: checked};
    const checkedItems = this.props[type].filter((item) => prevState[item.resumeId]);
    newState.isCheckd = checkedItems.length === this.props[type].length;
    newState.isEnable = checkedItems.length > 1;
    return newState;
  });
};
```

(Notice I've removed the `? true : false` from the lines setting `isCheckd` and `isEnable`. `===` and `>` **already** give you a boolean, there's no point served by adding a conditional operator there.)

Comment: Hi I have used this solution, but still I am facing the same issue that one does get update but the second one doesnot

Comment: So I added the spread operator for both tracked as well.And then it worked

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - Doh! That was a typo, fixed now. If your overall problem still isn't solved, though, we really can't help you further without that [mcve].

Comment: No my problem is resolved with your awsome solution. I just have one query that I have added some line of code in the question which is also doing the same thing, if you just look at that .that would be helpful

Comment: @GaneshKaspate - Glad that helped! (Once you filled in the missing `...` :-) ). I've updated the answer, but it's just the same answer again: Use the correct form of `setState`.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I'm facing same problem recently.but I got the solution.

```
const [data,setData] = useState([]);
const emails = ["127","hello1","here"];
emails.forEach((email)=>{
   setData((prev) => [...prev,emial])
 })
```

Above code gives me an error

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

***Solution***

```
const [data,setData] = useState([]);
const emails = ["127","hello1","here"];
useEffect(()=>{
 emails.forEach((email)=>{
   setData((prev) => [...prev,emial])
 })
 },[])
```

*Put forEach or map inside useEffect for avoiding the error and state will also update*

May be this answer helps some who facing same error